# How to copy selective row from multiple worksheets into one single panda dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, worksheet

I have an excel file containing sales data from 20+ regions with the same structures:

region1:

| Date | Car 1 | Car 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 12 |
| 2 | 12 | 13 |

region2:

| Date | Car 1 | Car 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 32 |
| 2 | 22 | 33 |

region3:

| Date | Car 1 | Car 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 | 32 |
| 2 | 32 | 33 |

I would like to copy one entire row (for car 1) from each worksheet and combine them into one data frame with the header as the date and different regions like below:

| Date | Region 1 | Region 2 | Region 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 21 | 31 |
| 2 | 12 | 22 | 32 |

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `concat`

```
out = pd.concat([x.set_index('Date')['Car 1'] for x in [df1, df2, df3]],axis=1, keys= ['region1','region2','region3']).reset_index()
out
Out[259]: 
   Date  region1  region2  region3
0     1       11       11       11
1     2       12       12       12
```